# Get distinct sets of fields from MongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I know it is possible using group method in MongoDB command line, however I can't find how to perform such a task in rmongodb library. At the moment I have to get all the values filtered by some parameters and then loop thorough them adding to a new data frame in case they don't exist there.

```
cursor = mongo.find(mongo, "db.col", list(filterfield="filtervalue"), fields = list(f1=1L, f2=1L))
df = data.frame(f1=character(0), f2=character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
while(mongo.cursor.next(cursor)){
  newf1 = list(mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor)))[[1]]$f1
  newf2 = list(mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor)))[[1]]$f2
  if(nrow(subset(df, df$f1 == newf1 & df$f2 == newf2)) < 1){
    df[nrow(df) + 1, ] = c(newf1, newf2)
  }
}
```

It seems extremely inefficient since grouping it in MongoDB takes orders of magnitude less time... Is there a simpler way through a direct MongoDB command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not that easy, but you can do it :-). The most challenge is to create the bson query and to use the runCommand syntax from mongodb. Here is some example code and the data you can find in docs.mongodb.org.

An example SQL query could look like this:

```
SELECT state, SUM(pop) AS totalPop FROM zips GROUP BY state 
HAVING pop > (10000)
```

In mongoDB shell you will run something like this.

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate( { $group :
                       { _id : "$state",
                         totalPop : { $sum : "$pop" } 
                       } },
                       { $match : {totalPop : { $gte : 10000 } } } 
                     )
```

You can run the same with the command db.runCommand which has the following default syntax for the aggregation framework:

```
db.runCommand(
 { aggregate : "article", pipeline : [
    { $project : {author : 1,tags : 1} 
    },
    { $unwind : "$tags" },
    { $group : {
         _id : "$tags",
         authors : { $addToSet : "$author" }
         } 
    }
  ] }
);
```

Now you can do the same in rmongodb with the following code:

```
buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "aggregate", "zips")
  mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "pipeline")
    mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$group")
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "_id", "$state")
      mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "totalPop")
      mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$sum", "$pop")
      mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
    mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
    mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "$match")
      mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "totalPop")
      mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$gte", "10000")
      mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
    mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
  mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)

res <- mongo.command(mongo, "test", query)

out <- mongo.bson.to.list(res)
```

Please let me know if this is not working.